# Can you do LINQ-like queries in a language like Python or Boo?

Tags: python, linq, linq-to-sql, ironpython, boo

Take this simple *C# LINQ* query, and imagine that `db.Numbers` is an *SQL* table with one column `Number`:

```
var result = 
    from n in db.Numbers
        where n.Number < 5
        select n.Number;
```

This will run very efficiently in *C#*, because it generates an *SQL* query something like

```
select Number from Numbers where Number < 5
```

What it **doesn't** do is select *all* the numbers from the database, and then filter them in *C#*, as it might appear to do at first.

*Python* supports a similar syntax:

```
result = [n.Number for n in Numbers if n.Number < 5]
```

But it the `if` clause here does the filtering on the client side, rather than the server side, which is much less efficient.

Is there something as efficient as *LINQ* in *Python*?  (I'm currently evaluating *Python* vs. *IronPython* vs. *Boo*, so an answer that works in any of those languages is fine.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that when IronPython 2.0 is complete, it will have LINQ support (see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/ironpy/browse_thread/thread/eb6b9eb2241cc68e) for some example discussion).  Right now you should be able to write something like:

```
Queryable.Select(Queryable.Where(someInputSequence, somePredicate), someFuncThatReturnsTheSequenceElement)
```

Something better might have made it into IronPython 2.0b4 - there's a lot of [current discussion](http://ironpython-urls.blogspot.com/2008/09/dlr-namespace-change-fire-drill.html) about how naming conflicts were handled.

Comment: IronPython 2.0 is just about complete, and I would say that we don't support LINQ at this point.

Answer (score 7):

[sqlsoup](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/SqlSoup) in sqlalchemy gives you the quickest solution in python I think if you want a clear(ish) one liner . Look at the page to see.

It should be something like...

```
result = [n.Number for n in db.Numbers.filter(db.Numbers.Number < 5).all()]
```

Answer (score 5):

Look closely at [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/).  This can probably do much of what you want.  It gives you Python syntax for plain-old SQL that runs on the server.

Answer (score 5):

LINQ is a language feature of C# and VB.NET.  It is a special syntax recognized by the compiler and treated specially.  It is also dependent on another language feature called expression trees.

Expression trees are a **little** different in that they are not special syntax.  They are written just like any other class instantiation, but the compiler does treat them specially under the covers by turning a lambda into an instantiation of a run-time [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).  These can be manipulated at run-time to produce a command in another language (i.e. SQL).

The C# and VB.NET compilers take LINQ syntax, and turn it into lambdas, then pass those into expression tree instantiations.  Then there are a bunch of framework classes that manipulate these trees to produce SQL.  You can also find other libraries, both MS-produced and third party, that offer "LINQ providers", which basically pop a different AST processer in to produce something from the LINQ other than SQL.

So one obstacle to doing these things in another language is the question whether they support run-time AST building/manipulation.  I don't know whether any implementations of Python or Boo do, but I haven't heard of any such features.

Answer (score 1):

Boo supports list generator expressions using the same syntax as python.  For more information on that, check out the Boo documentation on [Generator expressions](http://boo.codehaus.org/Generator+Expressions) and [List comprehensions](http://boo.codehaus.org/List+Generators).

Answer (score 0):

A key factor for LINQ is the ability of the compiler to generate expression trees.
I am using a macro in Nemerle that converts a given Nemerle expression into an Expression tree object.
I can then pass this to the Where/Select/etc extension methods on IQueryables.
It's not quite the syntax of C# and VB, but it's close enough for me.

I got the Nemerle macro via a link on this post: 
http://groups.google.com/group/nemerle-dev/browse_thread/thread/99b9dcfe204a578e

It should be possible to create a similar macro for Boo. It's quite a bit of work however, given the large set of possible expressions you need to support.
Ayende has given a proof of concept here:
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/05/Ugly-Linq.aspx

Comment: Nemerle supports Linq expression like C# and even more: http://code.google.com/p/nemerle/source/browse/nemerle/trunk/Linq/  . For example supporting Nemerle tuples with Linq:
      def xs = [(1,1,"aaa"), (2,2,"aaa")];
      def xs = xs.AsQueryable();
      def res = linq <# from p in xs select p[0] #>.NToList();